# Understanding joint probability distribution function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am new to the subject of probability and need someone to help me understand the following:

If I am given:
$$f(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
45xy^2(1-x)(1-y^2), & 0< x\leq 1,0< y\leq 1 \\
0, & \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

And I am asked to compute $$P(X>Y)$$

My understanding is that $$P(X>Y) = P(0< x\leq 1,0< y\leq x)$$
Based on this understanding I compute:
$$45\int\limits_{0}^{1}\int\limits_{0}^{x}xy^2(1-x)(1-y^2)\, dydx$$
Now where I need help for understanding is: I will have to integrate *y* first as such:
$$45\int\limits_{0}^{1}\left(x-x^2\right)\left(\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^5}{5}\right)dx$$
And then integrate everything as a whole again?  If the latter statement is correct, I would appreciate if someone could explain to me why.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is correct. Note that you should write 
$$
P(X>Y) = P(0<X\leq 1,0<Y\leq X),
$$
i.e. use $X,Y$ to denote the random variables and $x,y$ to denote the variables of integration.

Strictly speaking, the probability that you need to compute is
$$
\int_{A}f(x,y)\,\mathrm d(x,y),
$$
where $d(x,y)$ is the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ and
$$
A=\{(x,y)\in[0,1]\times[0,1]\ :\ y\le x\}.
$$
Writing the double integral as you did is justified by [Fubini's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Tonelli.27s_theorem_for_non-negative_functions). 
Since $f$ is non-negative,
$$
P(Y\le X)=\int_0^1\int_0^xf(x,y)\,\mathrm dy\mathrm dx=\int_0^1\int_y^1f(x,y)\,\mathrm dx\mathrm dy.
$$
In other words, you may integrate in any order, the end result will be the same.
You find
$$
P(Y\le X)=\frac{19}{56}.
$$